# how to find current active tab id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to create functionality for save the current tab on postabck.
for this reason:

1) How to find out the id of current  tab.

2) How can pass that id to hidden variable. 
I am not using jquery tabs due to some issue. I am creating script using plain jquery script.

**This is my JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs').each(function () {

            var $a, $c, $ = $(this).find('a');

            $a = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $a.addClass('active');
```

**This is HTML for tabs**

```
<div class="co">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"> Content 1 </div>
    <div id="tabs-2"> Content 2 </div>
    <div id="tabs-3"> Content 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI tabs, easiest way

As [**Docs**](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) getter of active JqueryUI tab is

```
var active = $(".tabs").tabs( "option", "active" );
```

Comment: how can i find using javascript

Comment: what do you mean by `find using javascript`?